# Zend DB select only 1 table with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm using Zend DB to generate a query using the following code:

```
$table->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false) //required for multi-table join
        ->from('modules')
        ->joinInner(
            'basket_modules',
            'modules.id = basket_modules.id')
        ->joinInner(
            'baskets',
            'baskets.id = basket_modules.basket_id')
        ->where('baskets.id = ?', $this->id);
```

This generates the SQL:

```
SELECT modules.*, basket_modules.*, baskets.*
FROM modules
INNER JOIN basket_modules ON modules.id = basket_modules.id
INNER JOIN baskets ON baskets.id = basket_modules.basket_id
WHERE (baskets.id = '3')
```

My problem here is with the SELECT part, it's selecting all 3 tables instead of just modules, which is the one I want. So the query I would want to generate is:

```
SELECT `modules`.*
FROM `modules`
#etc...
```

How can I do this? If I edit the query manually and run it, it returns what I want so there shouldn't be a problem with the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please look at the example in the manual [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join). Scroll to the Example #13.

> To select no columns from a table, use an empty array for the list of
>   columns. This usage works in the from() method too, but typically you
>   want some columns from the primary table in your queries, whereas you
>   might want no columns from a joined table.

```
$select = $db->select()
         ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
                array('product_id', 'product_name'))
         ->join(array('l' => 'line_items'),
                'p.product_id = l.product_id',
                array() ); // empty list of columns
```

Answer (score 2):

you can specify column name for other table and main table like below

```
$table->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false) //required for multi-table join
    ->from('modules',array('modules.*'))
    ->joinInner(
        'basket_modules',
        'modules.id = basket_modules.id',array('basket_modules.id'))
    ->joinInner(
        'baskets',
        'baskets.id = basket_modules.basket_id',array('baskets.id'))
    ->where('baskets.id = ?', $this->id);
```

so sql will be like

```
SELECT modules.*, basket_modules.id, baskets.id
FROM modules
INNER JOIN basket_modules ON modules.id = basket_modules.id
INNER JOIN baskets ON baskets.id = basket_modules.basket_id
WHERE (baskets.id = '3')
```

Comment: I think `array('basket_modules.id')` is wrong because we don't need to specify table name. Table alias is added automatically. This is why I think correct code would be `array('id')` or even empty array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$table->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false) //required for multi-table join
        ->from('modules')
        ->joinInner(
            'basket_modules',
            'modules.id = basket_modules.id',array(''))
        ->joinInner(
            'baskets',
            'baskets.id = basket_modules.basket_id',array(''))
        ->where('baskets.id = ?', $this->id);
```

Give a empty array as the third parameter of `join` otherwise it will select all the field from the table joined.If you want some fields then specify field names in the array while joining.